# Wrong orientation of Custom Camera captured image android

Tags: android, camera, orientation, image-rotation

**What I have**

I have a `CustomCamera` that captures images in both `LANDSCAPE & PORTRATI`

**My Problem**

When I capture the image , it gets saved in wrong direction (not w.r.t Camera orientation)

**What I want**
I wanted the camera to save photo in proper Orientation. I should detect dynamic screen orientation (but my **CameraActivity is restricted to PORTRAIT :(** )

**What I tried**

```
public  Bitmap flip(Bitmap src, int type) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        if(type == 0) { // portrait
            matrix.preScale(1.0f, -1.0f);
        }
        else if(type == 1) {  // landscape
            matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
        } else {
            return src;
        }
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
```

I tries using this by setting hard code values **0 & 1** but

This gives me **MIRROR image**

Answer (score 0):

-- Complete code for capturing image ,saving to SD card , pick from gallery,compress,rotate image,etc.. 200% working.

```
public class A extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AsyncTaskCompleteListener {

    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/idyme";
    private static int MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION = 200;
    private final String TAG = "RegisterFragment";
    private Button btnVerify, btnUploadImage;

    private String   ImgPath = null, filePath = null,
            profileImageFilePath, profileImageData = null,imageVideoType = "", imageVideoPath = "";
    private ImageView ivImage;
    private AQuery aQuery;
    private Uri uri = null;
    private ImageOptions imageOptions;
    ActionBar actionBar;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vip_registration);


        ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivProfile);
        aQuery = new AQuery(this);
        imageOptions = new ImageOptions();
        imageOptions.memCache = true;
        imageOptions.fileCache = true;
        imageOptions.fallback = R.drawable.userimage;






    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //  onRegisterButtonClick();

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btnUploadImage:
                showPictureDialog();
        }
    }

    private void showPictureDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        pictureDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(
                R.string.dialog_chhose_photo));
        String[] pictureDialogItems = {
                getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_from_gallery),
                getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_from_camera)};

        pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {

                            case 0:
                                choosePhotoFromGallary();
                                break;

                            case 1:
                                takePhotoFromCamera();
                                break;

                        }
                    }
                });
        pictureDialog.show();
    }

    private void choosePhotoFromGallary() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, Constants.CHOOSE_PHOTO);


    }

    private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                (cal.getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg"));

        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {

            file.delete();
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //   uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        uri = getOutputMediaFileUri();
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, Constants.TAKE_PHOTO);


    }

    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri() {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
    }

    private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
        String result;

        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, proj, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file
            // path
            result = contentURI.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            result = cursor.getString(idx);
            cursor.close();
        }


        return result;


    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == Constants.CHOOSE_PHOTO) {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri contentURI = data.getData();
                profileImageData = getRealPathFromURI(contentURI);
                // new AQuery(getApplicationContext()).id(ivMeme).image(
                // profileImageData, imageOptions);
                try {
                    String path = saveImage(scaleImage(this, contentURI));
                    imageVideoPath = path;
                    aQuery.id(R.id.ivProfile).image(
                            imageVideoPath, imageOptions);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Utils.showToast("Failed", this);
                }

            }

        } else if (requestCode == Constants.TAKE_PHOTO) {


            // old
            if (uri != null) {
                profileImageFilePath = uri.getPath();
                if (profileImageFilePath != null
                        && profileImageFilePath.length() > 0) {
                    File myFile = new File(profileImageFilePath);
                    String path = saveImage(BitmapFactory
                            .decodeFile(profileImageFilePath));
                    imageVideoPath = path;
                    aQuery.id(R.id.ivProfile).image(
                            imageVideoPath, imageOptions);
                } else {
                   Utils.showToast("Failed", this);
                }

            } else {
                Utils.showToast("Failed", this);
            }

        }

    }

    public String saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
        File wallpaperDirectory = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
        // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
        if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        try {
            File f = new File(wallpaperDirectory, Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                    new String[]{f.getPath()},
                    new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
            fo.close();
            AppLog.Log("TAG", "File Saved::-> " + f.getAbsolutePath());
            return f.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }


private static File getOutputMediaFile() {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                IMAGE_DIRECTORY);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY, "Oops! Failed create " + IMAGE_DIRECTORY
                        + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");

        return mediaFile;
    }

    public static Bitmap scaleImage(Context context, Uri photoUri)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
        BitmapFactory.Options dbo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        dbo.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, dbo);
        is.close();

        int rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight;
        int orientation = getOrientation(context, photoUri);

        if (orientation == 90 || orientation == 270) {
            rotatedWidth = dbo.outHeight;
            rotatedHeight = dbo.outWidth;
        } else {
            rotatedWidth = dbo.outWidth;
            rotatedHeight = dbo.outHeight;
        }

        Bitmap srcBitmap;
        is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
        if (rotatedWidth > MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION
                || rotatedHeight > MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION) {
            float widthRatio = ((float) rotatedWidth)
                    / ((float) MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION);
            float heightRatio = ((float) rotatedHeight)
                    / ((float) MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION);
            float maxRatio = Math.max(widthRatio, heightRatio);

            // Create the bitmap from file
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = (int) maxRatio;
            srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
        } else {
            srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        }
        is.close();

        /*
         * if the orientation is not 0 (or -1, which means we don't know), we
         * have to do a rotation.
         */
        if (orientation > 0) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(orientation);

            srcBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBitmap, 0, 0,
                    srcBitmap.getWidth(), srcBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        }

        String type = context.getContentResolver().getType(photoUri);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        if (type.equals("image/png")) {
            srcBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        } else if (type.equals("image/jpg") || type.equals("image/jpeg")) {
            srcBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        }
        byte[] bMapArray = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);
    }


    public static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri) {
        /* it's on the external media. */
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION},
                null, null, null);

        if (cursor.getCount() != 1) {
            return -1;
        }

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getInt(0);
    }

}
```

-- Permission required :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Comment: getting null pointer for cursor in getOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri).